# BlogEngine.NET multiple blogs at virtual directories - error 404

Tags: blogengine.net

BlogEngine.NET 2.5 supports multiple blogs, as you can see in [this post](http://allben.net/post/2011/06/19/Introducing-Multiple-Blogs-in-Single-Instance-for-BlogEngineNET.aspx), and it really does, i tested this feature with subdomains - works fine. But i can't get it work with virtual directories.

in the post you can read this:

> ...you do not need to create physical directories named blog1 and blog2. 
>   These are virtual directories that BE.NET will look for in the URL to
>   treat that request to the web server as being on behalf of those blog
>   instances.

I tryed to add ~/en virtual path from "Add new blog" option in Blogengin.NET settings but I got this error:

> HTTP Error 404 - File or Directory not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on IIS6 or IIS7?  I tested with IIS7, both integrated mode and classic mode app pools with success.  If you're on IIS6, it's possible one of the wildcard settings for the aspnet_isapi.dll need to be turned on (cannot remember offhand what that setting is).

Another thing to look out for is to make sure a physical directory for "en" does not exist.

Comment: I'm using IIS 7.5 and it is a asp.net 4.0 integrated mode pool, and of course the directory "en" does not exist at root of web application

Comment: Another thing to try.... try adding the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" attribute to the <modules> tag under <system.webServer> as shown below.

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="True" >
    ...
  </modules>
</system.webServer>

Comment: It works with "clean" instalation of the blog, but i was trying to make it work after upgrade to 2.5, so maybe I erased som files in app_data, so I have to check it out. But it works, thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm... wonder what the difference is.  I also just posted another idea above, but if you are going with a clean installation, then I guess you are set.